# Lit-Element - How to render template from an external text?

Tags: javascript, templates, eval, web-component, lit

I have a string which I receive from an external service which contains the HTML template with some expressions which need to be dynamically evaluated by the render function. How can this be done with Lit?  I tried with `unsafeHTML()` and as well with `unsafeStatic()` but the expression in my string `${new Date()}`get not evaluated and stays as text.

```
...
import {unsafeStatic, html} from 'lit/static-html.js';
import {unsafeHTML} from 'lit-html/directives/unsafe-html.js';

@customElement('my-component')
export class MyComponent extends LitElement {

    templ = "<div>${new Date()}</div>";

    render() {
        return html`${unsafeHTML(this.templ)}`;
    }

    // OR

    render() {
        return html`${unsafeStatic(this.templ)}`;
    }  

}
```

Output get evaluated as text: "${new Date()}" instead of the current date  like "19.05.2023"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using `eval()` function and nested `html`directives. May be someone has a better solution?

```
import {html} from "lit";
import { customElement, state} from "lit/decorators.js";

@customElement('my-component')
export class MyComponent extends LitElement {

    @state()
    templ = "<div>${new Date()}</div>";

    render() {
        // output as static text, template content not evaluated
        console.log(this.templ);
        // render the template content
        return html`${eval("html`"+this.templ+"`")}`;
    }
}
```

This works also with more advanced constructs like the one below. So you can retrieve the template`templ` from an external service and evaluate with the data you prepared. Hope this helps also others which may have similar requirements.

```
@customElement('my-component')
export class MyComponent extends LitElement {

    // produce an array with mixed elements which some of these need to be evaluated
    data = [`${new Date()}`, `${1 + 1}`, "text"];
    
    // create a template as string which later get evaluated
    @state()
    templ : any;
        
    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
            
           // receive the template content from an external service
           (async() => {
            await fetch("template.html")
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(text => {
                this.templ = text;
            });
        })();

    render() {
        console.log(this.templ);
        return html`${eval("html`"+this.templ+"`")}`;
    }
    
}
```

content of "template.html"

```
<div>${this.data.map(item => html`<li>${item}</li>`)}</div>
```

This produces something like this

```
<div>
    <li>>Fri May 19 2023 17:09:42 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>text</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your server is able to return the template within a javascript module response you might be able to import the template function from that file and then use it to produce what you want.  For example your server could return a javascript file on a request via a dynamic `import(requestURL)`:

```js
export template = (html, data) => html`<div>${new Date()}</div>
<ul>${data.items.map((i) => html`<li>${i}`}</ul>`;
```

I suppose in some ways this is a kind of an eval() except that it ensures everything abides by the same security levels and basic rules.  Dynamically returned module content has many interesting advantages and additional pitfalls.

I'm not sure if the reason you need to return templates dynamically stems from having a CMS with templates in it or something more like a hybrid of server-side-rendering and client-side, but dynamic imports obviously only return from http GET requests for URLs and you wouldn't be able to use this approach if you needed to bundle a bunch of data in the requests to the modules directly as a result.